# flutter installation exception： flutter Doctor

Tags: flutter

After I deleted the original flutter sdk, downloaded the latest stabel version of flutter, and then ran `flutter doctor`, this problem occurred, and I have not found a solution.

What happened? and How to solve it？Have you ever met？

`flutter doctor -v`

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!


#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:447:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:323:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PubDependencies.update (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:126:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:677:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1518:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```